# How to fix my my loadData method with my main class

Tags: java

I am trying to load data from a txt file and it will only read one line of the txt file. When I specify what the int I variable is in my for loop within my loadData method it will print that particular line. I am not sure why it won't just add and print all my data.

I tried using an outer for loop to see if would print and add the data that way, but no luck

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
public class BingoSortTest
{
static BingoPlayer [] test;
public static void main (String [] args) throws IOException
{
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
        test = new BingoPlayer [10];
        loadData();

            System.out.print(Arrays.toString(test));


}
public static void loadData() throws IOException    
{
    Scanner S = new Scanner(new FileInputStream("players.txt"));
    double houseMoney = S.nextDouble();
    S.nextLine();
    int player = S.nextInt();
    S.nextLine();

        for(int i = 0; i < test.length; i++)
        {
            String line = S.nextLine();
            String [] combo = line.split(",");
            String first = combo [0];
            String last = combo [1];
            double playerMoney = Double.parseDouble(combo[2]);
            BingoPlayer plays = new BingoPlayer(first, last, playerMoney);
            add(plays);
        }

}
public static void add(BingoPlayer d)
{
    int count = 0;
    if (count< test.length)
    {
        test[count] = d;
        count++;
    }
    else
        System.out.println("No room");
 }
}
```

Here is the contents of the txt file I am using:

- 50.00
- 10
- James,Smith,50.0
- Michael,Smith,50.0
- Robert,Smith,50.0
- Maria,Garcia,50.0
- David,Smith,50.0
- Maria,Rodriguez,50.0
- Mary,Smith,50.0
- Maria,Hernandez,50.0
- Maria,Martinez,50.0
- James,Clapper,50.0

Comment: Note that all capital case names are usually reserved for static variables. Your `Scanner S` does not conform to this rule.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every Time you put a BingoPlayer at Index `0` .

```
public static void add(BingoPlayer d)
{
    int count = 0; // <-------------------- Here
    if (count< test.length)
    {
        test[count] = d;
        count++;
    }
    else
        System.out.println("No room");
 }
```

you have to define static counter variable where array of BingoPlayer is defined.

define count variable static

```
static BingoPlayer [] test;
static int count = 0;
```

and chane the add function definition like this.

```
public static void add(BingoPlayer d)
{
    if (count< test.length)   {
        test[count] = d;
        count++;
    }
    else
        System.out.println("No room");
 }
```